# Track Real Time location of smartphone phone in php

Tags: yii2

I have a yii2(php framework) web application and I want to track the real time location of smartphones in this website on basis or smartphone unique id.
Please help to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Real time of  machines can access by client-side languages like javascript , not server side lang like php(yii2) . you have to write a custom javascript and send it to your controller in yii2 by Ajax .